# How to use standard field type file in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I am trying to upload a file and i have used joomla xml form in joomla 2.5 version. This form inserts image name in database. but file is not uploaded. Is there any tutorial for use of standard field type file in joomla form.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you could provide some code. What's the code you use that you expect to save the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use the [media form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/Media_form_field_type) example:

```
<field name="myimage" type="media" directory="stories" />
```

You might have used the [imagelist form field type](http://docs.joomla.org/Imagelist_form_field_type) example:

```
<field name="myimage" type="imagelist" default="" label="Select an image" description="" directory="" exclude="" stripext="" />
```

Which sounds like it is the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the image uploaded using File in Joomla 2.5 is stored in temp folder. Uploading image using "media" seems working but with limitations :

- The user must have sufficient permission to do so.
- if the user has permission, he can actually view everything in the folder which is not interesting situation

Using File is the better solution but you will need to write some php code to retrieve the uploaded image.

I know this is not an answer,it's just to show the way. I have the same problem and will be writing the php code shortly to manage the upload.I will update you with outcome.

Jacques